# date picker on cloned function, date is changing only for first <input>

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have to use date picker on cloned function, calender is opening for all cloned  but date is changing only for first

My jQuery is:

```
var newclass= 0;
jQuery("#addpublication").click(function () {
$(".another_pub:last").clone().find("input:text").val("").end().appendTo(".pub_clone");
            $(".publication_date").each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass().addClass("form-control publication_date newclass"+newclass);
    $(".newclass"+newclass).datepicker({
                 dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                 }); 
               newclass++;
    });
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: I am Cloning

<input class="publication_date" name="publication_date[]" data-msg-required="required" type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />


Callender is opening for all cloned element, But Its changes the date of first element